# load pdf viewer from a hyperlink of pdf file inside webview

Tags: android, pdf, webview

Has anyone managed to invoke a pdf viewer to display pdf files upon clicking a hyperlink inside webview? If so, can you share some idea how you accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Override shouldOverrideUrlLoading to intercept all urls and when you detect a pdf file in the url fire an intent to show the pdf.

Detecting if a url is a pdf file might require you to download to a stage where you can access the mime type.

Then to show the pdf in an external application look at 
[Reliably detect PDF support on Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901104/reliably-detect-pdf-support-on-android-device)