# Reliably detect PDF support on Android device

Tags: android, pdf

I am using a method to detect pdf support on an Android device that goes like this

```
public boolean canDisplayPdf() {
    PackageManager packageManager = application.getPackageManager();
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    if (packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And that has been working great so far. I know that at least the HTC default viewer, droidreader and adobe acrobat get reported that way and the right result is returned. However I now got a comment on the market console by a user that says that he has pdf support on the device, but from the described behaviour of the app I conclude that this method returns false.

Is there any better way to detect pdf support?

PS: I would love to be able to ask the user for details on the market.

Comment: What do you mean by ask the user for details on the market?  Like checking to see if they have a PDF reader installed before they install your application?

Comment: I can not start a conversation with a user about a comment on the Android market. Sometimes it would be great to be able to do that. In this case e.g. it would be great to know what pdf application is installed since it has a bug in that it does not react to this intent imho... and I could report this bug to the makers of said application.

Comment: It looks like whatever pdf viewer they're using is not set to use CATEGORY_DEFAULT when handling intents. You could get around this by using 0 for your flag instead of PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY, but that could give you spurious results if for some reason there are apps out there that are intentionally registering for ACTION_VIEW on pdfs but don't want to be used for viewing them. That doesn't seem likely, but it's a wide world so you never know. :)

What you're doing is the correct way. I agree that it'd be nice to be able to respond to users, as these issues are painful otherwise.

Comment: You shouldn't rule out the possibility that the user stating he had PDF support on his device was incorrect :).

Comment: Just because there is a PDF viewer doesn't mean that it registers an intent filter for that file type - the user could have to open the app first, browse a list of files and then open one from there. Ask the user what PDF reader they have. Tell them to download the Adobe PDF reader if possible and then try again.

Comment: If only I could ask the users.. it was a comment on the android market... no way to ask.

Comment: How about offering a "download PDF" option as well as "view PDF" (which I assume you are disabling when canDisplayPdf() returns false)?  That way the user can download the PDF and view it in whatever way they usually do.

Comment: That does not work since viewing it from the app provides a lot more context and data related to the pdf that would be missing outside the app and therefore not be much good.

Comment: Man you are awesome, you are awesome. Thank you, yes your approach is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From all sources I found and practical experience testing on a rather large variety of devices the approach I have taken is correct.

I have not had any further feedback and think there might have been user error or a bad pdf application version involved.

Comment: No idea why you got a down vote - so I've just given you a +1

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it correctly. You could consider updating the description of your app to say that you invoke a PDF app using the Android-approved method with the application/pdf MIME type. And also mention that if users have any trouble with the app, you'd appreciate an email to blahblah@myappsupport.com (or whatever your app support email address is setup to be). Maybe then they'd send an email instead of just leaving an anonymous comment.