# read local pdf through webview

Tags: android

I am doing one application to read pdf from sdcard through webview. I used the following code.

```
 webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/MotoronAug.pdf");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    webview.loadUrl(uri.toString());
```

but i got a blank page. But when i give a web address

```
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.google.com%2Farchive%2Fbigtable-osdi06.pdf");
```

I can read it from webview what is the problem in my code?...I have MotoronAug.pdf file in my sdcard.Help me friends

Comment: This answers your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655972/android-webview-pdf

Comment: so...I can't open a pdf offline in webview right???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Online or local both wont be rendered by webview.

Comment: is there any framework in android like quartzcore in IPhone to support pdf reading

Comment: I don't know what this quartzcore is, but if you have to detect pdf support, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901104/reliably-detect-pdf-support-on-android-device